# Cant find contour lines raster extraction

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation, contour

I am trying to create contour plot concentration data to a map. [I followded this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkKIbSdFZFI)  and have interpolated the data as follows:
 [image]

but, while forming contour lines, I am not finding the raster> Extraction> Interpolation
I tried finding it in plugin but, I don't seem to find it there. What is the error I am making?
[image]

Comment: Are you working in QGIS 2.18? You may as well check the Plugins Manager too see if `GdalTools` has been ticked.

Comment: it was just a guess, but I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relatively rare, but sometimes we encounter a situation `GdalTools` plugin is not activated.

[image]

In an extreme case like below, we miss lots of raster tools.

[image]

In your case, the Plugin Manager will have below tools activated:

- Heatmap
- Interpolotaion plugin
- Raster Terrain Analysis
- Zonal statistics

But probably the **GdalTools** plugin is unchecked. Ticking it on will solve the issue.

---

NB. This issue is QGIS 2.18 specific.